# Mongoose MissingSchemaError with Mocha test

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, mongoose, mocha.js

I'm trying to use mocha to test my API, but it fails with an `Uncaught MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Kitchen".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)` every time I call a method on the model that uses `populate(field)`.

Minimal example: https://gist.github.com/connors511/6204164 (transaction.js being the offender)

I've also tried using the method as a schema.statics, but it returns the same result as the example.

If I remove the `populate('where.kitchen')` from the `_listForUserClub` method, it fails for MissingSchema Club instead.

Any idea what's causing this, or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the issue by using

```
var _model;
try {
    _model = mongoose.model('ClubTest', _schema);
    _model.singular = 'clubtest';
} catch(e) {
    _model = mongoose.model('ClubTest');
}
```

instead of

```
var _model = mongoose.model('ClubTest', _schema);
_model.singular = 'clubtest';
```

for all my models after finding the workaround at https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongoose-orm/PXTjqqpaDFk/tYx1ge04GlsJ